# How Can I change/trigger the dirty Flag of an Angular Form Using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm trying to change the `dirty` flag of a `form` using JavaScript through its DOM element.

To achieve this, I'm utilizing `@ViewChild` to access the element and then reading it in the `ngOnInit` lifecycle method (it can be done in different ways, but the goal in this step is to get the native element).

Once I have the form's DOM element, I attempt to dispatch an event to the form to change/trigger the `dirty` flag.

However, this approach isn't working.
Does anyone have suggestions on how to accomplish this?

[stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-fuzdrt?file=src%2Fmain.ts)

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule, FormsModule],
  template: `
    <h1>Welcome from {{ name }}!</h1>
    <a target="_blank" href="https://angular.io/start">
      Discover more about Angular
    </a>

    <form #ngForm="ngForm" name="ngform">
      <input [(ngModel)]="foo" name="foo">
    </form>

    Is it dirty? {{ngForm.dirty | json}}
  `,
})
export class App {
  name = 'Angular';

  @ViewChild('ngForm', { static: true, read: ElementRef }) form!: ElementRef;
  foo = '';

  ngOnInit() {
    const el = this.form.nativeElement;
    el.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
    console.log({ el });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read the `NgForm` instead of the `ElementRef` and use the [`markAsDirty`](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#markAsDirty) method:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule, FormsModule],
  template: `
    <h1>Hello from {{ name }}!</h1>
    <a target="_blank" href="https://angular.io/start">
      Learn more about Angular
    </a>
  
    <form #ngForm="ngForm" name="ngform">
      <input [(ngModel)]="foo" name="foo">
    </form>

    dirty? {{ngForm.dirty |json}}
  `,
})
export class App {
  name = 'Angular';

  @ViewChild('ngForm', { static: true, read: NgForm }) form!: NgForm;
  foo = '';

  ngOnInit() {
    this.form.control.markAsDirty();
  }
}
```

Comment: yeah, but it's not from the DOM element. I looking a way to do that from the DOM element. trigger event that cause the dirty to changed.

Comment: what's the end goal? why do you need to do it like that?

Comment: It's complicated to explain. I have some js vanilla code that have a lot of `input` that they outside of angular form. kind of webcomponent inside that form: `<form>....<webcomponent></form>` and I need that just to trigger the `dirty` flag when the input inside webcomponent is changed. thats it.

Comment: you could maybe wrap your webcomponent inside another component that implements the `ControlValueAccessor` interface. That's a little less hacky in my opinion. It also helps with `touched`, not only dirty. Also with the value binding, value change propagation and all those nice things.